# Why won't Fragment Transaction work?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I'm writing a simple program in which a two fragments and one activity is used.  Both Fragments are displayed (one at a time) within the activity's Frame Layout.  The first fragment is a listview that lists items from which the user can select, then the main activity should swap the first fragment with a detail fragment according to the item position determined by a listener within the first fragment.  Trouble is, my program won't actually commence the swap.  Here's the code for the activity:

```
package com.example.user.monkeys;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;

public class ListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements       
monkeyListFragment.OnMonkeySelectedListener {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("Activity", "onCreate Pre-Fragment 1");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.monkey_list_frame);


    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }


        monkeyListFragment monkeyList = new monkeyListFragment();


        monkeyList.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the container
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, monkeyList);

        Log.i("Activity", "made it end onCreate");
    }
}

@Override
public void onMonkeyItemSelected(int position) {
    Log.i("From Activity", "onMonkeyItemSelected");
    monkeyDetailsFragment newDetailFrag = new monkeyDetailsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("itemPosition", position);
    newDetailFrag.setArguments(args);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newDetailFrag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

And the code for the listview fragment:

```
package com.example.user.monkeys;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class monkeyListFragment extends Fragment{

OnMonkeySelectedListener monkeyCallBack;
private ListView monkeyLV;
private String[] monkeyStrings;

public interface OnMonkeySelectedListener {
    public void onMonkeyItemSelected(int position);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("Fragment 1", "Made it to onCreateView");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

    monkeyLV = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.monkeyListView);
    monkeyStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.monkey_data_list);

    ArrayAdapter<String> objAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, monkeyStrings);
    monkeyLV.setAdapter(objAdapter);

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener monkeyListen = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("ListFragment-ClckLstnr", "Made it");
            monkeyCallBack.onMonkeyItemSelected(position);

        }
    };

    Log.i("Fragment 1", "Made it past OnItemClick Listener");
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        monkeyCallBack = (OnMonkeySelectedListener) activity;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
    }
}
}
```

and finally the code for the detail fragment (this isn't fully fleshed out but it should still swap I believe).

```
package com.example.user.monkeys;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class monkeyDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

ImageView monkeyPicture;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("From Detail Fragment", "Got here");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.monkey_detail_fragment, container,      
false);

    return view;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your missing line of code for the listview fragment:

```
monkeyLV.setOnItemClickListener(monkeyListen)
```

Comment: Yep, that was exactly it!